# AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

Tags: apache, mod-auth, mod-authz-host

I'm running apache 2.4.6 on my site. And I keep seeing this message repeated over and over again in my apache error logs.

```
[Tue Nov 10 01:42:40.659710 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10727] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 107.170.139.115:58678] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
```

Here's how the root directory for this site is listed in the VHOST:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jf-beta
    <Directory /var/www/jf-beta>
      Options  -Indexes  +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Exactly what is Apache complaining about here? That directory listing seems perfectly reasonable to me! And how do I get it to stop complaining about this error?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is not an error, nor is apache complaining about it. If you look closely at the log statement, it says:

```
[<date>] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10727] <stuff>
```

Notice that there's **`authz_core:debug`**. It means that you have set the [`LogLevel`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/core#loglevel) directive to `debug`. Change the value to `error` or `warn` and you'll stop seeing the logged statement anymore.

Comment: But is it normal to have thousands of these line in the debug level log?

Comment: @wruckie Yes. The log levels imply severity of the logged message. _debug_ level messages are just used as checkpoints by developers to easily trace where the error originated. (and also to provide a verbose output as to how the program is working)

Comment: I found out that i was under a DOS attack, seeing these by the thousands helped me figure out what was going on.   
 http://serverfault.com/questions/667914/underused-apache-server-raise-maxrequestworkers-reached-memory-leak/800126#800126

Comment: Just for curiosity: Have someone tried that in bash?:
`GET / HTTP/1.1/ HTTP/1.1authorization result of Require all granted: granted`